# Pytorch install with anaconda error

Tags: anaconda, pytorch

I get this error:

```
C:\Users>conda install pytorch torchvision -c soumith
Fetching package metadata .............

PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - pytorch
```

I got `conda install pytorch torchvision -c soumith` from [Pytorch official website](http://pytorch.org/) and I have OSX/conda/3.6/none for settings on Pytorch site(should be correct). I am new to conda, any tips how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following commands to install pytorch on windows

for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, CUDA 8

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda80
```

for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, CUDA 9

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda90
```

for Windows 7/8/8.1 and Windows Server 2008/2012, CUDA 8

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch_legacy cuda80
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** From PyTorch 0.4, there is an official Anaconda channel with packages for Windows as well.
You can install the latest pre-built (binary) version of PyTorch (GPU version by default) on windows using:

`conda install -c pytorch pytorch`

For CPU only version:
`conda install -c pytorch pytorch-cpu`

For specific version of CUDA say CUDA9.1:
`conda install -c pytorch pytorch cuda91`

Official instructions for windows are now available [here](https://pytorch.org/)

**Old answer for previous versions (<0.4) of PyTorch on Windows:**

It looks like you are on windows (win 64) and you are trying to install pytorch by choosing OSX because you don't have an option listed for win64 on [pytorch site](http://pytorch.org). (Correct me if that is not the case, I will revise my answer). `-c soumith` will use soumith's channel which only has packages for Linux and OSX not for windows. That is why you got that error when you ran conda from a windows machine.

You can install pytorch on windows through conda using this command:

`conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch`

This will fetch the pytorch package using peterjc123's channel which has packages for Win64.

You can install the torchvision package using pip like this:
`pip install torchvision`

Comment: Using peterjc123's package, I get the error No module named 'torchvision'

Comment: Please do not use these packages. They are broken and overwrite core parts of `conda`. See https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/2533

Comment: @PabloGonzalez You can install torchvision using pip like this: `pip install torchvision`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I noticed that a few days ago and now everything goes well with pytorch.

Answer (score 3):

On June,2019, The command generated at pytorch will require dependencies before it can be executed successfully. For example I chose stable pytorch 1.1 build with python 3.6 and Cuda 10.0. The command generated by pytorch page was as follows:

> conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch

But it will not work if you have created a new conda environment like me. The step by step process for setting up pytorch is as follows:

- First install the cudatoolkit as follows:

> conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=10.0

- Then install the mkl_fft as follows:

> conda install -c anaconda mkl_fft

- Assuming you will face no more dependency issues. Use the following command to setup pytorch:

> conda install -c pytorch pytorch

This worked for me. But I had setup my new conda environment with scikit-learn and jupyter notebook before starting the pytorch setup. So if any dependency problem arise, it would be a good idea to install both scikit-learn and jupyter notebook as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have face similar problem because I have installed  pytorch cpu only version. I tried everything and update pytorch to gpu version but nothing helped.
Simple solution is to create new environment and then install pytorch gpu version. It  resolve my problem